# {Beginner Turtle graphics} Nested while loop runs infinitely?

Tags: python

I can execute the code fine and everything but I want it to stop running after the 8 tails are complete. I've been having similar issues with other nested loop projects where even with the condition defined, the loop refuses to stop running. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

The code:

```
import turtle
turtle.width(20)
turtle.speed(0)

#outerloop: pink tail
turtle.up()
tail_count = 0
while tail_count < 8:
    turtle.color("salmon")
    turtle.goto(0,0)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.circle(75,180)
 
#innerloop: yellow ends
    end_count = 0
    while end_count < 4:
        turtle.color("yellow")
        turtle.circle(30,45)
        turtle.color("gold")
        turtle.circle(30,45)
        turtle.color("yellow")
        turtle.circle(30,45)
        turtle.color("gold")
        turtle.circle(30,45)
        turtle.up()
        end_count = end_count + 1
    turtle.left(45)

tail_count = tail_count + 1
turtle.done()
```

Comment: Do you know what is `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line: `tail_count = tail_count + 1`
Is not inside the first while loop so `tail_count` is not getting bigger inside the loop.